# Question about C++ global variable in JNI on android

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

Is using C++ global variable in JNI on android acceptable?

If so, I'd like to know the life-cycle of it.

When a.cpp is connected to b.java and instance of b is created(is global variable initialized at this point?) and destroyed(is global variable destroyed at this point?).

In a nutshell, global variable in C++ side share it's won life-cycle with connected Java instance?

Comment: Does the global variable reference a `jobject`? If not it is simlpy tied to the lifecycle of the native library that hosts the variable.

Comment: If I bind native-lib in constructor scope(not static) of b, then is it destroyed when instance b destroyed?

Comment: No. As I said, the lifetime of native objects is tied to the native library. Whatever happens in the Java worls is irrelevant.

Comment: then do you know the life-cycle of the native library?
when I bind native-lib like below----------------------
class b {
    init {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib")
    }
}

Comment: It stays loaded until the classloader that loaded it is destroyed. In practice it stays loaded forever.

Comment: I really appreciate. Do you have any reference on what you've pointed out...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lifetime of native objects is tied to the lifetime of the native library that hosts them.
This, in turn, is governed by the lifetime of the Java ClassLoader that [loaded the library](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/jni/invocation.html#library-and-version-management):

> In addition, native libraries can be unloaded when their corresponding class loaders are garbage collected.

In Android applications that will never happen, so you can assume that your native objects survive as long as the application does.